# Generate and edit csv-file to reimport and use it with blender

Tags: python, scripting, csv

Case: 
I'm exporting a list of coordinates from vertices (x, y, z-Coordinates) to a csv. file.

```
import bpy  
import os

main_path = os.getcwd()
print("writing to: " + main_path + "\n\n")

outputfile = 'G:\\final\\list_of_Vertices.csv'
with open(outputfile, 'w') as w_file:

for i in bpy.context.active_object.data.vertices:  
    print(i.co," ")  
    coords = i.co.x, i.co.y, i.co.z  
    w_file.write(str(coords)+" \n")
```

So what I get is a csv file like this:

(-8.9578,-10.9873,6.8372)
...

When I try to use this file again to work with the coordinates blender gives me the error:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(-8.960794448852539'...).

My question:

How can I get rid of the braces so that I can use the generated csv file?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Suggest this is more a [python question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44781/5317130) than blender.   `write(",".join(map(str, coords))`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is primarily about python.