# Saving and loading object name location and rotation of a selection

Tags: python

I would like to know how I can save selected object names, location and rotation using Python in Blender 2.8 in a CSV.

And then using the same CSV apply this information to another blend file with the same objects in different locations in a new frame.

(it's not about bones it's about normal meshes).

Beeing new to Blender Python scripting, I hope for some coding hints here.

so far i got this (works in console but not in script file)

```
import bpy
import os
ob_active = bpy.context.selected_objects
for obj in ob_active:
    print(obj.name,obj.location,obj.rotation_euler)
```

Comment: [That's python in blender](https://i.imgur.com/BSZL31w.png), [this is Python in Blender](https://i.imgur.com/xeWmjYW.png)

Comment: well its a start (and a funny joke), the thing i have problems with is exporting and importing to a .csv

Comment: CSV is just comma separated values in a text file with .csv extension. The first Google result for "Python write to file" will help: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Comment: yes but the way blender logs those values (as in above of my script) isnt a normal table with values logge4d as <vector > etc

Comment: Look into string formatting in Python. You need to convert the values you are using to strings as well. You can do: `some_string_var = ', '.join([str(x) for x in obj.rotation_euler])` to get the rotation values separated by commas as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Surely this has been asked before?**

*Rather than spending any more time searching for the elusive dupe, to the export part, I'm sure it's out there*

Here is an example using f-string formatting.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

def sfmt(s):
    return f"{s :10s}"

def vfmt(vec):
    return ", ".join(f"{v : 10.4f}" for v in vec)

for obj in sorted(context.selected_objects, key=lambda o: o.name):
    output = ",".join((
            sfmt(obj.name), 
            vfmt(obj.location), 
            vfmt(obj.rotation_euler),
            ))
    print(output)
```

Output of default scene, remember rotations are in radians.

```
Camera    ,    7.4811,    -6.5076,     5.3437,    1.1093,     0.0000,     0.8149
Cube      ,    0.0000,     0.0000,     0.0000,    0.0000,    -0.0000,     0.0000
Lamp      ,    4.0762,     1.0055,     5.9039,    0.6503,     0.0552,     1.8664
```

A number of other csv related questions.

[How to read a csv file and use the values as x and y points in blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71458/how-to-read-a-csv-file-and-use-the-values-as-x-and-y-points-in-blender)

[Massive import with CSV file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119865/massive-import-with-csv-file)

[Moving and rotating using CSV](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142024/moving-and-rotating-using-csv)

[Generate and edit csv-file to reimport and use it with blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87395/generate-and-edit-csv-file-to-reimport-and-use-it-with-blender)

[How do I move an object using a csv file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131454/how-do-i-move-an-object-using-a-csv-file)

[How to import a 3d object by csv file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74378/how-to-import-a-3d-object-by-csv-file)

[csv file reading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130988/csv-file-reading)

[Exporting coordinates of vertices to CSV](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51706/exporting-coordinates-of-vertices-to-csv)

[Import coordinates from CSV and create sphere at each position](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95145/import-coordinates-from-csv-and-create-sphere-at-each-position?r=SearchResults&s=24|34.6325)

Comment: thanks your vfmt   code is realy handy

Comment: Actually prob shouldn't restrict name string to 10 characters.  For any length if put last it wont naff formatting. `math.degrees(v)` will convert if degrees needed for csv.